# PrefixQuery on multiple fields and based on another field's value?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am working on an auto complete solution with lucene. Do I need to call the PrefixQuery each time for each field I want to search on? Also, what if I only want to search a small set of items based off another filed's ID?

For example: Let's say I have a list of users that I have indexed. Those users belong to a specific project. I only want to PrefixQuery search users that are on, say, projectId 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your schema has fields "projectid" and "name", you would query for documents (users) matching the query:

```
+projectid:1 +name:prefix*
```

where 1 is the projectid and "prefix" is the name prefix you want to search for.